Enable "Find my device" on just one account
I have two Google accounts on my phone. My personal one and a corporate one. Currently, from any machine logged in either accounts, I can find my device.
Although there's nothing nefarious about my whereabouts, I do not wish the admin of my corporate account to know where my phone spends its evening. Is there a way to disable "Find my device" for just one account?
I see the "Device Finders" -> "[On/Off]" switch. However that seems to control both accounts at once.

Dupe: How to use multiple Google accounts, but allow only one to locate my phone in device manager (2016, outdated),  Use multiple Google accounts, but allow only one to locate my phone in device manager (2019, no answer yet)

Reiterating my comment, an admin would have to reset your password then log into your Workspace account to be able to track your location, therefore you would get an alert to your device if this happened.
However, an admin wishing to track you, or an admin account that became compromised could do this. Therefore, it looks like private space is the way to go on Android 15:

To keep your sensitive apps away from prying eyes, you can set up private space, a separate space on your Android device to hide and organize apps.
With private space, you can:



Create a digital safe within your phone for the apps you don’t want others to easily access or find. These apps can isolate their data from the rest of your phone.
Switch seamlessly between main profile apps and private space.
Set up a separate lock for an extra layer of authentication.


So you'd install your corporate apps in private space, with private space logged into your Workspace account. You would have the main phone outside of private space logged into your Gmail only.
I tested this with Find My Device on a Workspace account and I get Find My Device is turned off. If you install Find My Device in private space, the UI directs you to turn it on in settings, but this appears to link to the whole device's setting rather than private mode. So this appears to be the way to turn Find My Device off for one account but not the other. In addition, if you lock private space, the apps can't run in the background, so even if Find My Device was on the location wouldn't be up to date.
Related article on Android Police regarding using Private Space for work-life split.
